# Expected number of rounds?

Tags: probability

Every round you get 1 point with a chance of $p$ and 2 points with a chance of $1-p$. How many rounds can be expected to get $N$ points?

If I am not mistaken $$E(N) = pE(N-1)+(1-p)E(n-2)$$ and $E(1)=1$ and I think but not quite sure of $E(2)=p^2+1-p$. (Excuse me being unsure here, I need this for a video game, my probability exam was near thirty years ago and I barely passed it and I haven't touched the subject really since then.)

Comment: WHat you wrote is right. But to solve the recurrence maybe it is easier to write it as: $$E(N)=(p^2+1-p)E(N-2)$$

Comment: So then $E(N) = (p^2+1-p)^{N/2}$ for even N?

Comment: exactly, what about for $N$ odd?

Comment: Upps sorry, that is for computing the exact probabilities, not the expected value....

Comment: The $N$ in your question is a fixed number (not a random variable). Expressions like $E(N)$ and $E(N-1)$ do not really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value for $1$ round is $1\cdot p + 2\cdot(1-p) = 2-p$

So by linearity of expectation, expected # of rounds needed to get $N$ points is simply $\frac{N}{2-p}$

**Note**
As remarked by lulu, this doesn't hold for small number of rounds.

Comment: Sorry, apologies, an error of mine. I erase this comment.

Comment: This is certainly true in the limit, but for small $N$?  If $N=1$ the answer is clearly $1$ (you will certainly achieve at least $1$ point in the first round), not $\frac 1{2-p}$  Similarly $E(2)=(1-p)\times 1 +p\times 2=1+p$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $E(N) = pE(N-1)+(1-p)E(N-2) + 1$ (account for the one round you just played)

Also $E(N)$ for all $N\leq0$ is $0$. Now you can get $E(1)=1$, $E(2) = p+1$, $E(3) = p^2+2,  \dots$

Note: These denote expected rounds of getting $N \textbf{ or more}$ points (because we set $E(-1)=0$). If you want exact points expected rounds then set two variables $p(N)$ (chance of hitting $N$ points at some point) and $E(N)$ (expected rounds to reach $N$ points given we hit it)

Comment: In the question $N$ is a fixed number so notations like $E(N)$ and $E(N-1)$ are not really okay. You better go for something like:$$\mu_{n}=p(1+\mu_{n-1})+(1-p)(1+\mu_{n-2})=1+p\mu_{n-1}+(1-p)\mu_{n-2}$$ Then $\mu_0=0$, $\mu_1=1$, $\mu_2=p+1$, $\mu_3=p^2+2$ and to be found is an expression for $\mu_N$.

Comment: @drhab Ehhh, that feels like too much professionalism expected by a game developer who just wants to know what to implement for a very specific part of his game